Range header confusion with ASP.NET MVC upload
I am migrating an inherited ASP.NET MVC application on .NET 4.5.2 to AWS. I have an upload component that is failing in the new environment and the failure appears to be regarding the Range header. I find that on the first upload attempt the call is successful and the Range header is present and correctly populated (I can see the value in my debug session and I can see it in the F12 tools).
Debug:
public JsonResult UploadFileBlock(long uploadId) 
{
    // we have range header here in the request when we succeed.
    var rangeHeader = Request.Headers["Range"];

    return Json(FileManagerClient.UploadFileBlock(uploadId, Request, base.Upn));
}

F12 console:
Priority: u=1,i 
Range: bytes=0-246096

On the second upload attempt in succession I find the Range header is Null at the controller breakpoint, however it is still present in the F12 console and carries the correct value for whatever file I am trying to upload. If I refresh the upload page before attempting a second upload the Range header is present again in the controller and the workflow is functional.
I don't understand what is happening to the Range header in this workflow. I suspect some configuration in IIS, CloudFront, or the ALB may be stripping the header out but I cannot find any evidence of this. I am also trying to determine if this is somehow associated with HTTP1.1 vs HTTP2. Our old environment is running under HTTP1, I have played with CF and ALB configurations and forcing HTTP1 does not seem to correct the situation. I am hoping someone can shine a light here and help me understand, any insight would surely be appreciated.
